# Equivalent to regex backreferences in Access query?

Tags: regex, backreference

I'm trying to write a query in Access that will search a string for a key word/words, and then return the following n characters. In other words, for the string

```
Account number: 123456 Status: 3
```

it would extract the account number: `123456`.

In UNIX-land, I would use parentheses to capture the string of interest after scanning for "Account number: ". I'm struggling to do the equivalent in Access - any suggestions?

Comment: [Here is a tutorial](http://bricestacey.com/2010/07/09/Regular-Expressions-in-MS-Access.html) that covers regular expressions in MSAccess that I think will be helpful.

Comment: Thanks! I'll see if I can my use my (very) limited VBA skills to get something along the lines of what you linked to solve my problem. I am still curious though if anyone fielding the question knows whether there's a more "Access-native" solution.

Comment: Having not dealt with MSAccess personally, does it have its own independent syntax?

Comment: I really don't know - I was just trying to help someone and all they have to work with their data is Access (corp environment), but I'm not an Access guy...